# Java ObjectOutputStream on Socket not flush()ing

Tags: java, sockets, flush, objectoutputstream

I'm working on a network app written in Java, using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream on top of Sockets to exchange messages. My code looks like this:

Sender:

```
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
try{
     Socket socket=new Socket(address, port);
     socket.setSoLinger(true, socketLingerTime);
     out=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     out.writeObject(message);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
}catch (variousExceptions)...
```

Receiver:

```
Object incoming;
try{
    incoming=myObjectInputStream.readObject();
}catch (SocketException socketError)
{
    if (socketError.getMessage().equals("Connection reset"))
    {
        //this is the exception I get
    }
}
```

Sometimes the message goes through ok, but other times I get the marked exception instead of an object. Isn't flush supposed to force the message through to the other side? Am I somehow using the function incorrectly? Or is this some sort of bug in the underlying Java/OS network code?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I've done some more snooping on this, and it seems to only happen when the system's resources are being taxed by something. I've not been able to replicate it outside the VirtualBox, but that could just be because the VirtualBox doesn't have many resources to begin with. I'll keep this question updated as I look into it further.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. More details?

Comment: can you show more of your receiver code?  are you trying to send/receive more than one message over the same socket (in which case you shouldn't be closing the streams).

Comment: are there any exceptions thrown on the sender side when you get the connection reset on the receiver?

Comment: OS is Red Hat Linux, running in VirtualBox on top of Windows XP. I do send and receive multiple messages, over the same socket; this only happens when the sender close()s its stream, so I stripped the other message code out. There are no exceptions on the sender side when it happens.

Comment: Oh yeah, and I'm using jdk1.6.0_23.

Comment: I've had similar issues with VirtualBox and creating network connections. From what I can tell, it's not a problem with Java or your code, but a problem either in VirtualBox, or Windows. What type of network connection do you use for the Client OS?

Comment: I'm connecting to localhost. It could be something with VirtualBox or Windows...like I said in the update, I've not been able to replicate it on native linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by Nagle's Algorithm; the output buffer is within the OS, so it wasn't affected by flush. The solution is to turn Nagle's Algorithm off using Socket.setTcpNoDelay(true), and buffer messages at the user level using BufferedOutputStream.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, it's a silly problem but wasting me 4 hours.
Just have to use **outStream.writeln("");** or **outStream.write(mess + "\n");**
Since **reader.readLine()** reads until it finds **'\n'** character. So write() alone won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to send one object per connection.

To ensure resources are cleaned up in an orderly manner it is best to close the socket as well as the output stream.

close() will call flush so it should be redundant.

What happens if you don't set the SO Linger?

What is the actual exception you are getting?

Comment: You should be able to send multiple objects.

Comment: @Highland, if you don't close() the output after sending the first object. ;)

Comment: I actually added the SO Linger thing as a possible fix for this problem. The issue still occurs without it.

Actual exception is SocketException, message "Connection reset".

Comment: This exception does mean the other end closed the connection, however the code you have shouldn't do that and doesn't reproduce the problem for me.  I would make absolutely sure that the code you are testing is what you think it is. close() calls flush() for you so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a firewall in one of the routers in the path from client to server is sending an RST for some reason.  I don't believe there's anything wrong with your code.  I tried to replicate the problem, but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Connection resets can be caused by writing to a connection that is already closed at the other end. Detection can occur at the next I/O or a subsequent one, e.g. a read. In other words it can be caused by a bug in your application protocol. SO_LINGER won't help, don't mess with this.